# Code conversion from Objective C to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a project in Objective-C and trying to convert it to Swift. It is a Large project. Is there any possibilities to convert it in the same project or have to create a new project?

Comment: ObC-to-Swift Converters are generally useful for syntax conversion in limited scopes, where you may have a few lines of code written in C and you simply want to see it written in Swift. For those moments, I use https://objectivec2swift.com/ and it works very well. But for entire projects, you should definitely not rely on these kinds of converters.

Comment: I'm asking whether we have to to create a new project for swift conversion or convert files in the same project?

Answer (score 6):

There is no automated conversion.

Also the development paradigm on Swift is quite different to ObjC (optionals, nested functions/functions as objects, functional programming).

Therefore it will be a manual process of refactoring.

You can combine the two languages though. If you feel your objective c codebase is good enough to keep, why not consider writing the next feature in Swift?

Comment: We are planning to convert entire project to Swift as it is our application stabilisation time. So, will it be better to convert the existing file to Swift files in a separate branch or should we start a new project and replace everything?

Comment: Exactly there is great tool to convert snippets to swift.https://objectivec2swift.com/. I converted SVProgressHUD to swift using it. https://github.com/Swiftify-Corp/IHProgressHUD, https://medium.com/swiftify/converting-svprogresshud-to-swift-using-swiftify-27be1817b7f6

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer creating a new project and adding files to it.
Even if it takes time, it will be clear for developers like us. 
Creating a branch will do solve the problem, but them when it comes to merging and stuffs, it will take hell lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I will be merging only with swift branch. Will it take lot of time for that too?

Comment: Anytime :) @SherineSJ